# Drupal 7 hook_form_submit

Tags: drupal

I'm trying to modify the file description field inside the `form_alter` function by using the `form_submit` function.

In my `hook_FORM_ID_alter()` function I'm assigning a new data array as:

```
function hook_FORM_ID_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $field['data']['description'] = 'some value';
  $form['field_upload']['und'][0]['#default_value'] = $field;
}
```

Then in my `hook_form_submit()` function, I'm trying to pass the value into another function at the same time store it inside my `field_upload_description` field

```
function hook_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $values = $form_state['values'];
  $doc = $values['data']['description'];
  $result = some_other_function($doc);
}
```

Nothing happens. As a matter of fact, when I go back to edit the node, the file is no longer attached in the file field.

I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change $form_state values.

Answer (score 1):

You did a mistake in the declaration of the hook function, so your first function is probably not called !!

1. The name of the function is : hook_**form**_FORM_ID_alter
2. Be careful, in Drupal **7**, the fonction uses a third argument : **$form_id**, whereas this third argument is not in the Drupal **6** equivalent function.

#### The good function declaration (for Drupal 7):

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter() for FORM_ID().
 */
function hook_form_YOUR-FORM-ID_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

}
```